# Understanding nested random effects - why is an interaction between factors involved?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have read this question and answers:

[Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified)

however, I am struggling to understand why, provided that the factors are coded correctly, the nesting is equivalent as a random intercept for the **interaction** between the two factors, along with random intercepts for the upper level factor. The latter makes sense to me, but the former (the interaction) does not. I am looking for an **intuitive explanation** about why this is so.

As a specific example, using the answer above, suppose that we have classes nested within schools:

```
> library(lme4)
> dt <- read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

> dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")

> m0 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school) + (1 | classID), data = dt)
> summary(m0)

> m1 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1 | school) + (1|classID:school), data = dt)
> summary(m1)
```

These 2 models are equivalent, and the output for the random effects sections are:

```
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classID  (Intercept)  8.2043  2.8643  
 school   (Intercept) 93.8409  9.6872  
 Residual              0.9684  0.9841  
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  classID, 24; school, 6
```

and

```
Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 classID:school (Intercept)  8.2043  2.8643  
 school         (Intercept) 93.8409  9.6872  
 Residual                    0.9684  0.9841  
Number of obs: 1200, groups:  classID:school, 24; school, 6
```

Why is the random effect for `classID` in the first model identical to the random effect for the interaction `classID:school` in the 2nd ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the random effect for classID in the first model identical to the random effect for the interaction `classID:school` in the 2nd ?

That is because `classID` and `classID:school` are indeed the same, in this dataset. That is, the nesting structure is explicit in the way that the factor `classID` is coded - each level of `classID` "belongs" to one and only one level of `school`. That is precisely why the answer to that linked question has this line of code:

```
 > dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")
```

which creates a new factor for which the levels are unique to each level of `school`. As explained in that answer, the original dataset does not have explicit nesting - it could be fully cross-classified (or just "crossed" for short) or it could be fully nested.

**By specifying random intercepts for the interaction between the two factors, we also make exactly the same structure as the line of code above, but without having to create a new variable to do so.**

To see this more clearly:

```
> dt <- read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

> xtabs(~ school + class, dt)

        class
school  a  b  c  d
   I   50 50 50 50
   II  50 50 50 50
   III 50 50 50 50
   IV  50 50 50 50
   V   50 50 50 50
   VI  50 50 50 50
```

there is an ambiguity about whether these are (fully) nested, or (fully) cross-classified (crossed).  If we know that they are nested then we specify the random intercepts in `lme4` as:

`(1|School/Class)` or equivalently `(1|School) + (1|Class:School)`

whereas if they are crossed then we specify the random intercepts as

`(1|School) + (1|Class)`

Notice that, in the answer given to the linked question, this problem is resolved, if the data are nested, by introducing a new variable, `classID` such that each class ID is unique to the school to which it "belongs" (which is the definition of nesting):

```
> dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")
> xtabs(~ school + classID, dt)

      classID
school I.a I.b I.c I.d II.a II.b II.c II.d III.a III.b III.c III.d IV.a IV.b
   I    50  50  50  50    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0
   II    0   0   0   0   50   50   50   50     0     0     0     0    0    0
   III   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    50    50    50    50    0    0
   IV    0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0   50   50
   V     0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0
   VI    0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0

      classID
school IV.c IV.d V.a V.b V.c V.d VI.a VI.b VI.c VI.d
   I      0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   II     0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   III    0    0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   IV    50   50   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
   V      0    0  50  50  50  50    0    0    0    0
   VI     0    0   0   0   0   0   50   50   50   50
```

which shows that each level of class occurs only in one level of school.

However, if instead, we form the interaction between class and school manually:

```
> dt$int.school.class <- interaction(dt$school, dt$class)

> xtabs(~ school + int.school.class, dt)
```

then we obtain *exactly* the same cross-tabulation:

```
> xtabs(~ school + int.school.class, dt)
      int.school.class
school I.a II.a III.a IV.a V.a VI.a I.b II.b III.b IV.b V.b VI.b I.c II.c III.c
   I    50    0     0    0   0    0  50    0     0    0   0    0  50    0     0
   II    0   50     0    0   0    0   0   50     0    0   0    0   0   50     0
   III   0    0    50    0   0    0   0    0    50    0   0    0   0    0    50
   IV    0    0     0   50   0    0   0    0     0   50   0    0   0    0     0
   V     0    0     0    0  50    0   0    0     0    0  50    0   0    0     0
   VI    0    0     0    0   0   50   0    0     0    0   0   50   0    0     0
      int.school.class
school IV.c V.c VI.c I.d II.d III.d IV.d V.d VI.d
   I      0   0    0  50    0     0    0   0    0
   II     0   0    0   0   50     0    0   0    0
   III    0   0    0   0    0    50    0   0    0
   IV    50   0    0   0    0     0   50   0    0
   V      0  50    0   0    0     0    0  50    0
   VI     0   0   50   0    0     0    0   0   50
```

[The cross tabulations might look different at first glance but this is solely because the ordering of the columns is different]

When we specify the interaction in the random part of the model formula `(1|Class:School)` that is what `lme4` is doing internally - without the need to creating a new factor.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1) cleared up my confusion as well! So, there is really no interaction effect in the sense that we use `x:y` as in the fixed part of the model?